# Bounded operator on pre-Hilbert spaces

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

There is a theorem on "Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces" by Joachim Weidmann

> Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be normed spaces. Let $T$ be an operator from $H_1$ into $H_2$.
> If $H_2$ is a pre-Hilbert space and $M$ is a subspace of $H_2$ such that $R(T)\subset \overline{M}$, then
> $T$ is bounded if only if
> $$sup\{|\langle T(f),g\rangle| : f \in D(T), g \in M, \|f\|=\|g\|=1\}<\infty$$
> This number is then equal to $\|T\|$.

For the right direction; $(\Rightarrow)$ of the proof was proved in the book. Now I am trying to prove by the left direction, that is

> If $\|T\|=sup\{|\langle T(f),g\rangle| : f \in D(T), g \in M, \|f\|=\|g\|=1\}<\infty$ then $T$ is bounded.

I have tried some steps like this:
Let $\|T\|=sup\{|\langle T(f),g\rangle| : f \in D(T), g \in M, \|f\|=\|g\|=1\}<\infty$, then the upper bound of $\{|\langle T(f),g\rangle| : f \in D(T), g \in M, \|f\|=\|g\|=1\}$ is exist, i.e. for all $f\in D(T)$ and $g\in M$, there exists $M>0$ so $$|\langle T(f),g\rangle|\leq M$$

then I am stuck on that step. I think, I can't use the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality because I don't know whether $\|T(f)\| \|g\| \leq M$ or not.
Can anyone give me any idea to prove this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $T$ linear ?

Comment: @Ramanujan yes, $T$ is linear operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be the supremum you have defined. Let $f \in D(T)$ and $\|f\|=1$. Then $Tf \in \overline {M}$ so there exists $(g_n) \subset M$ such that $\|Tf-g_n\| \to 0$. Now $\|Tf\|^{2} = \langle Tf, Tf \rangle =\lim \langle Tf, g_n \rangle \leq \lim  \|g_n\|\|Tf\|$. Dividing by $\|Tf\|$ we get $\|Tf\| \leq C $ whenever  $\|f\|=1$.

[I have used the fact that $ \langle Tf, h \rangle \leq C \|h\|$ if $f \in D(T), h \in M$ and $\|f\|=\|h\|=1$. This follows by writing $ \langle Tf, h \rangle$ as $\|h\|  \langle Tf, h/\|h\| \rangle$ and using the definition of $C$].